# How to generate custom "todo" tags in JetBrains IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, clion, todo

I have figured out how to download and install new color schemes.

It is after I did this that I noticed that IntelliJ will still color the following line yellow:

```
// ToDo: implement
```

Further, this coloration is independent of the color schemes I download. So, I now surmise that it is colored that way due to some logic specific to the Intellij.

I also use PyCharm and CLion, and suspect it would be the same situation across all three.

---

Here is the question: **how do I** access these settings/xml/logic and specify that I want say, 5 types of comment tags with colors A, B, C, D, E, such that I can call them by saying stuff like:

```
// T-A: File read in (t would be type)

// T-B: transform data

// T-C: linear section

// T-B: transform again

// T-D: parallel section

// T-E: MPI update

// T-B: array read in

// T-A: File read out

// etc.
```

So that I can basically color code the regions of a project, rather than just use the "ToDo" line?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can go to `Preferences` | `Editor` | `TODO`. And there you can add / remove / edit your own patterns and filters, including color scheme:

[image]

After that, in your `TODO` window there's a `Filter` button with option to Edit filters, so you can easily find all places in your code with your custom patterns.

[image]

Comment: You mention that you can edit the color scheme, but for me those are greyed out. I can just activate or deactive the options, when 'Use color scheme TODO default colors' is inactive.

Comment: @JBecker might be because of Ultimate Edition vs Community Edition features. I had Ultimate one

Answer (score 3):

The problem was already answered quite well but I would like to add the usage of non-word tags like `???`.

This requires to adopt the regex boundary character from `\b` *(word boundary)* to `\B` *(non-word boundary)*. This leads to the final pattern `\B\?\?\?\B.*` to match:

```
code // ??? comment
code // ???: comment
```

This was not directly asked but may helps other with the same problem as I met...

See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html