# How to highlight comments in several different colors in CLion?

Tags: comments, syntax-highlighting, clion

I code on C++ and i would like to have different colors for comments. For example, // todo is be default blue but I also want to have a red one, so i can highlight important stuff

I have looked at all the posts on StackOverflow and on the Net, but I did not find anything useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate custom "todo" tags in JetBrains IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547178/how-to-generate-custom-todo-tags-in-jetbrains-ide)